# Play Framework- How to return play.twirl.api.Html

Tags: java, scala, view, playframework, twirl

The main menu of my application (view1) contains options that must be displayed only when the user is logged (view2). In view1 a controller method is called. This method checks the user and returns view2 with the user as parameter.

View1:

```
@import com.feth.play.module.pa.views.html._
<div class="container-fluid">
     <ul>
        <li><a href="#">menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menu 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="logged">
    @controllers.HomeController.showOptions()
</div>
```

Method in HomeController:

```
public Html showOptions(){
    final User localUser = getLocalUser(session());
        return view2.render(localUser);
}
```

View2:

```
@(logged: User = null)
@if(logged!=null) {
    <div id="userMenu">
        <ul class='nav'>
            <li><a href="#">user option 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">user option 2</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

The compiler shows this error:

> value showOptions is not a member of controllers.ReverseHomeController

I don't have much experience with play, so i am not sure that is the right way to call a controller method. I have tried also with

```
@routes.HomeController.showOptions()
```

But then I get

> Cannot use a method returning play.twirl.api.Html as a Handler for requests

All help is appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: I guess you should use includes here instead of calling the controller again: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaTemplateUseCases#Includes

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `loggedUser` to the first template in order to pass it through to the second template:
View 1:

```
@(user: User)
<div class="container-fluid">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menu 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="logged">
  @view2(user)
</div>
```

View 2 can stay as it is. The corresponding controller for `View 1` would look something like this:

```
public Result showView1() {
    final User localUser = getLocalUser(session());
    return ok(view1.render(localUser));
}
```

Comment: I tried to avoid passing parameters to View1 ... but i guess this is the easiest way.  Thanks !

Comment: The only alternative would be to create a REST API and make dynamic AJAX calls from the client.